# Which variance did I get? How to get the population variance?

Tags: r, anova

Which variance did i get?
And how to get the population variance?

I run my data with subsampling model like this:

```r
#copy data#
cabaisubsampling <- read.table("clipboard",header=T,sep="\t")
cabaisubsampling$aksesi <- factor(cabaisubsampling$aksesi)
cabaisubsampling$blok <- factor(cabaisubsampling$blok)
cabaisubsampling$subsampel <- factor(cabaisubsampling$subsampel)

#cek struktur data#
str(cabaisubsampling)

mod <- lmer(diameterbatang ~ aksesi + blok + (1|subsampel),
            data=cabaisubsampling)
mod%>% 
  VarCorr()%>% 
  as.data.frame()%>% 
  select(grp, vcov)

mod%>% anova(ddf="Kenward-Roger")

**and the result :**
VarCorr()%>% 
+   as.data.frame()%>% 
+   select(grp, vcov)
        **grp       **vcov**
1 subsampel      0.00341192
2  Residual      0.18992486**

> mod%>% anova(ddf="Kenward-Roger")
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Kenward-Roger's method
        Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
aksesi 20.4906  0.4879    42   212  2.5688 5.523e-06 ***
blok    3.7416  3.7416     1   212 19.7007 1.456e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I tried to search the population variance with this:

```r
#The population variance can be calculated by 
#multiplying the sample variance by (n-1)/n as follows
n <- length(cabaisubsampling)
n
#population variance
var(cabaisubsampling) * (11-1)/11
```

Is it correct?

Comment: What do you think your length(canaisubsampling) produces as a result? And what is your question actually? Be much clearer please if you like to get a meaningful answer. E.g. which popul.variance would you like to know, of which variable?